# Error during Gauss Jordan method in Octave.

Tags: functional-programming, octave, gaussian

## matrix

```
a=[1,1,1,9; 2,-3,4,13; 3,4,5,40]
```

row operations

```
e=a(2,1);
for j = (1:4)
b=a(1,j)/a(1,1);
c=e*b;
d=a(2,j) -c;
a(2,j)= d;
endfor
```

row operations

```
e1=a(3,1);
for j = (1:4)
b=a(1,j)/a(1,1);
c=e1*b;
d=a(3,j) -c;
a(3,j)= d;
endfor
```

row operations

```
e2=a(3,2) 
for j = (2:4)
b=a(2,j)/a(2,2);
c=e2*b;
d=a(3,j) -c;
a(3,j)= d;
endfor
```

row operations

```
e3=a(2,3)
f=a(1,3)
for j = (2:4)
b=a(3,j)/a(3,3);
c=e3*b;
g=f*b
d=a(2,j) -c;
h=a(1,j)-g
a(2,j)= d;
a(1,j)=h
endfor
```

row operations

```
e4=a(1,2)
for j = (2:4)
b=a(2,j)/a(2,2);
c=e4*b;
d=a(1,j) -c;
a(1,j)= d;
endfor

a

b1=a(1,4)/a(1,1);
printf('\nx = ', b1);
b2=a(2,4)/a(2,2)
printf('\ny = ',b2);
b3=a(3,4)/a(3,3)
printf('\nz = ',b3);
```

In my octave terminal, this program gives right output for only once.
value of z is not printing
value of x is showing value of y
value of y is showing value of z

Comment: Use `printf('\nx = %f', b1);` to print the value of `b1` (notice the additional `%f`), and do the same with the others.

Answer (score 1):

There are few mistakes in the upper program 
Such as i am using variable'f' which is also the file name so that's why the program was not running again. Also in the printf section ' %d ' was missing.